# Laravel jwt-auth I Dont Use a Standard Laravel User Table

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Laravel has no user standard User model and users table. The programmer before me planned this way.I want to add jwt to distribute api to the project.

Table structure in which users are kept is as follows (table name **client_users**)

- @property int $id
- @property int|null $client_id
- @property string|null $client_name
- @property string|null $client_pass
- @property string|null $client_phone
- @property string|null $client_mail
- @property string|null $api_token
- @property string|null $remember_token
- @property string|null $visible
- @property string|null $deleted_at

First of all, the file used instead of the User model is as follows.

The model file is as follows **ClientUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
// class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject

class ClientUser extends Model implements JWTSubject
{

    protected $connection = 'remoteMysql';

    protected $table = "client_users";

    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

The config auth file is as follows. DIR **config/auth.php**

```
<?php    
    return [
        'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],
        'guards' => [
            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'jwt',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],

        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => \App\ClientUser::class,
            ],
        ],

        'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

What is different in the controller part is that we query with the customer phone and password instead of the standard email password

The Api/AuthController.php file is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['client_phone', 'client_pass']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your advice and help. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work because when you call `auth()`, it uses the default authentication guard, which is `web` in your case but this one does not exist. You need to replace it by `api`. Therefore, calling `auth()` will be exactly the same than `auth('api')`